# nginx avoid zipping images

Tags: nginx, gzip

I have set up nginx to serve gzipped versions of files (gzipped with a script). I do not want images (png and others) to be gzipped. So I have used

```
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

Still nginx is looking for ziped versions as seen in strace.

```
open("<path>/static/assets/<path>/up.png.gz", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory).
```

Is something wrong wit my use of gzip_types?

Comment: that just shows nginx opening the .gz file to read and send out, which is what you want, right? your gzip_types looks right. do a request in curl etc and see what headers nginx returns for the file request. (don't trust your browser, and some antivirus products ungzip to check also)

Comment: The message says "No such file or directory", which is right because the files are not there. I have not gzipped image files. But I do not want nginx to search for gzip versions of image files and then fall back to the non-gzipped files. That is a minor overhead, right? I want nginx to look for gzipped versions of certain types(css, java script...), and straight away use the original files for images.

Comment: So you're requesting up.png and you're seeing nginx open "up.png.gz"? do you have cacheing turned on in nginx? >>check for gzip_static in nginx config.<<

yes you're right, if you know the files aren't there, no point in looking for them.

Comment: I do have gzip_static on. But if I specify gzip_types and omit png and other image files, won't nginx automatically avoid looking for them? Or is it that the directive gzip_types doesn't apply for static files?

Comment: This link provides the answer - 
[refer]  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972675/how-to-tell-gzip-static-not-to-look-for-image-files

Comment: Thanks for adding that! Hadn't thought of those options. Feel free to put that in an answer below and accept it.

Comment: I did that. But since it was short, stackoverflow converted that to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

the gzip_static module tells nginx to look for a precompressed file (.gz) for any file it would normally serve.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html

This module is independent of the gzip module

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html

so the gzip_types doesn't apply to it. I don't see a way to selectively turn it off.